# Laravel count issue

Tags: php, laravel, count

I am trying to search by check-boxes and conditions but i get this error in return:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

### Logic

1. I can select 1 or more options
2. In back-end check what kind of options has selected
3. Depend of the kind return results

## Code

`controller`

```
public function advancedsearch(Request $request) {
    $options = Specification::whereHas('subspecifications')->with(['subspecifications' => function($query) {
        $query->status('Active');
    }])->get();
    $brands = Brand::all();
    $brandss = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];
    $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? (int)Input::get('suboptions') : [];
    $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? (int)Input::get('min_price') : null;
    $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? (int)Input::get('max_price') : null;

    //codes
    if(count($request['suboptions'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->join('product_subspecification', function ($join) {
        $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
                 ->where('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', $suboption);
        })
      ->paginate(12);
    }

    elseif(count($request['brands'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
      ->paginate(12);
    }

    elseif(count($request['min_price']) && count($request['max_price'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price])
      ->paginate(12);
    }


    return view('front.advancesearch', compact('products', 'brands', 'options'));
    }
```

**Summary of code above**

I am getting all brands from database and check if only 1 brand has selected or several

```
$brands = Brand::all();
$brandss = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];
```

Then I check if any brand has selected in general or no by `count` and returning results

```
elseif(count($request['brands'])){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
      ->paginate(12);
}
```

but I get error I share above.

Any idea?

## Update

`how my html look likes`

[image: one]

`how the result **dd** look like`

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "Wqs9yzd5qwGtbv01asbCzsISeVQxHsCoWVQM1ifO"
  "brands" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "3"
  ]
  "min_price" => null
  "max_price" => null
]
```

`Blade`

```
<div class="checkbox">
    @foreach($option->subspecifications as $suboption)

        @if($option->title == 'Brand')
            <label for="brands">
            <input name="brands[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$suboption->id}}">
            {{ucfirst($suboption->title)}}
            </label>
        @else
            <label for="suboptions">
            <input name="suboptions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$suboption->id}}">
            {{ucfirst($suboption->title)}}
            </label>
        @endif

    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: What's your HTML look like? Is your input named `brands[]` so that it comes back as an array?

Comment: @miken32 this is how it looks like https://ibb.co/gKDhvA

Comment: Edit your question to include the *relevant* HTML. I'm not going to click on that link.

Comment: @miken32 updated! ......

Comment: That looks fine. Your `dd()` output shows you are getting an array, so that code is not causing the error message. But it also shows `min_price` and `max_price` are null. Why are you trying to use `count()` on them? That's where your problem is.

Comment: @miken32 I count them incase they have value, `e.g.` user select brand **HP** price between **X** to **XX**

Comment: That's not how `count()` works, as the error message tells you. It's for counting arrays or other `Countable` objects.

Comment: so how to fix this? I have 3 kind of inputs, `brands` `suboptions` and prices `min_price, max_price`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Changed count with has solved the issue

```
elseif($request->has['brands']){
```

> **PS:** Based on 3 different functions that I have, which returns data of my search I have mixed results but it doesn't related to this
>   question. `count` error solved so I'll mark it as solved.

Thanks to **miken32**